Enable GPIO Sysfs interface on yocto mickledore
I'm trying to get my application to run on a new Yocto Mickledore Image I created. My application is failing to interface to the GPIO's and upon some research I found it is because GPIO sysfs interface is deprecated and GPIO chardev interface is now used (see here)
I really don't want to have to modify my application to make use of the new GPIO interface. Is there a way to configure my yocto image to make use of the old GPIO sysfs interface via /sys/class/gpio/export

Is CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS set in your kernel build?

I don’t know the lifespan of your application, but not rewriting it just delays the problem and increases technical debt as at some point in the future the old ABI may just gone.

@0andriy  Agreed - the OP absolutely should switch to the character device uAPI ASAP.  There is no reason not to, as libgpiod has been long available in yocto, and sysfs has been deprecated since 2016 - how much notice do people need??. But I wanted to confirm that the default kernel build config was the immediate issue before writing up a complete answer, as that was his question.  One of these days the long deprecated sysfs interface WILL be totally removed, not just compiled out by default.
